# jump to a section on different page is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have navbar like this :

```
               <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                 <li><a href="/main_page#top_something">People</a></li>
                 <li><a href="/main_page">Main Page</a></li>
               </ul>
```

but when I click on "People" link, it will not position correctly, because I am loading some charts on that page. I have many section with unique id and content is loaded from JavaScript (charts).

```
       <section id="top_something">
         <div class= "container">
          <h2 class="blue-headings text-center"><b>Top People</b></h2>
          <div id="div_something"></div>
         </div>
        <br>
    </section>
```

The content of a div id="div_something" I am making in JavaScript ...
I have a 10 div's like this on that main_page with unique id. I can see that when I click on a a href="/main_page#top_something" on navbar it will paste me on that section , but as soon as it loads JavaScript it will move me upper

thanks in advance

Comment: try to but extension after main_page
like main_page.html#top_section

Comment: I can't do that , because my main_page is a .ejs file that node.js(express) is rendering on that route

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39884440/jquery-scroll-to-id-on-page-a-from-page-b-node-ejs/39904667#39904667

Answer (score 0):

If your `main_page` is a directory (which it probably is) then you need to simply include a slash before the anchor name.

```
<a href="/main_page/#top_something">People</a>
```

If you have JavaScript injecting content after the page loads then you will be brought to the appropriate anchor but the page may move because the additional content added by JS will push the anchor down the page. You might consider repositioning the screen to the appropriate anchor using JS after its done injecting content.

Comment: no, it is a name of a file, .ejs file more precisely

Comment: even if I do onclick="location.href='main_page/#top_something' it is not working.